# Python For Loop to click on an image

Tags: python, for-loop

I am newbie at python and i want to ask your help and guidance in order how to create a code that will click on a image.

There are 20 rows on a page and as you can see in my example the rowindex is 0 but there are 20 rows per page. I would like to click on the image title "Details". When i click on this image a new window will open and i have to do some tasks on it.

My Code architecture is like a for loop to click on the image Details onto all the 20 rows.

Thank you in advance,
I
the html code is like this:

```
<tr m_rowindex="0" m_rpsid="40450661" m_suborg="chn" style="background-color: white;">
    <td>chn
    </td><td>0014B00000Oin17QAB
    </td><td>ACCT
    </td><td>CPY2
    </td><td>Street<br>City, chn 75892<br>United States
    </td><td>Potential Match
    </td><td>06/06/2017 02:28
    </td><td>XML_ACCT
    </td><td>06/06/2017 02:28
    </td><td>ADP_XML_ACCT
    </td><td><a href="#" onclick="return Go(event, 1)"><img title="Screen" src="/common/images/screen.bmp"></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

Comment: You need selenium http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/getting-started.html#simple-usage

Comment: Thank you! I know i need selenium, but i need your help in order to know which code should i use in order to do that.

Comment: if someone can help, i would owe nb you a lot!